# Run Rails with Passenger on Apache with Plesk

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have everything installed as per this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-rails-4-app-with-apache-and-passenger-on-centos-6

But when I go to the website, I get an error, and in the error log it shows this:

```
[ 2015-02-26 16:17:47.3041 28207/7f7326058780 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:728 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[Thu Feb 26 16:17:47.305819 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28184] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9 Phusion_Passenger/4.0.59 mod_perl/2.0.9-dev Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Feb 26 16:17:47.305844 2015] [core:notice] [pid 28184] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[ 2015-02-26 16:22:04.7157 28225/7f2c65840840 apache2/Hooks.cpp:151 ]: A filesystem exception occured.
  Message: Cannot stat '/var/www/vhosts/blah.blah/httpdocs/config.ru
  Backtrace:
     in 'void Passenger::DirectoryMapper::autoDetect()' (DirectoryMapper.h:144)
     in 'bool Hooks::prepareRequest(request_rec*, Passenger::DirConfig*, const char*, bool)' (Hooks.cpp:374)
```

Can anyone help?

The config.ru file was auto generated by rails, and it has these lines:

```
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.

require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run BlahBlah::Application
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be related to the following things:

- config.ru file is not exists by the specified path

  Try to execute command for check this:

  ```
  ls -la /var/www/vhosts/blah.blah/httpdocs/config.ru
  ```
- Passenger doesn't have permissions to read this file

  Try to execute command for check this:

  ```
  namei -lm /var/www/vhosts/blah.blah/httpdocs/config.ru
  ```

P.S.
  I noticed you are using shared hosting. Don't use them if you want to avoid a lot of different problems. Use VPS servers instead. Like Digital Ocean or Linode for Rails applications.